# How to set the shadow color for Image?

Tags: iphone

Hai, I am doing one application, in that i want to provide the shadow color for image after setting the border color. But border color and shadow color both are different. So please tell me any more suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [`CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)? It has a property called `shadowColor`. This works you are referring to an `UIImageView` object. If you're referring to the image, you can look at `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` to add an image using `Quartz`.